# Add syntax highlighting to Middleman proxy generated pages

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, syntax-highlighting, middleman

I have a number of pages on my Middleman blog that are generates via `proxy`. The data for the pages lives in a sub-directory in the `data/` directory, and the proxy call is like so:

```
data.projects.each do |slug, project|
  proxy "/projects/#{slug}.html", "templates/project.html", :locals => { :project => project }, :ignore => true
end
```

As an example of what one of those `data` pages would look like:

```
title: Metadata
image: projects/metadata.png
github: https://github.com/smargh/metadata
tags:
  - python
description: A Python module for searching your local files using metadata queries.
readme: |
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, *consectetur* adipiscing elit. Sed tristique ut quam non fermentum. In a sodales mi.
  Ut non **ullamcorper** ante, sit amet sagittis diam. Ut turpis orci, malesuada a lacus eu, fringilla faucibus felis.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur [adipiscing]() elit. Aliquam nec est at nibh mattis mattis eget sit amet leo.
  Cras tristique vestibulum nisi. Fusce iaculis venenatis metus, vitae luctus nunc blandit eget.
  Integer et nunc sed augue varius varius eu et elit. Suspendisse eu nisl venenatis, vehicula mi eu, rhoncus mauris.
  Integer magna diam, sodales a volutpat vel, cursus posuere nisi.
```

When generating the page, I use a simple `helper` method to convert the Markdown text in `readme` into HTML:

```
helpers do
  def markdownify(content)
    Tilt['markdown'].new { content }.render
  end
end
```

Thus, in the `project.html.erb` file, I have this line at one point:

```
<div id="description"><%= markdownify project['readme'] %></div>
```

This works well enough, but my syntax highlighting isn't used when generating these pages (as opposed to "normally" generated pages, where it works perfectly). Middleman uses `Rouge` for its syntax highlighting.

My assumption is that the data pipeline for proxy-generated pages is such that the `:syntax` code is never called.

My question is how to have my text run through the syntax highlighter, such that the resulting HTML is properly rendered? Do I need to add another helper method? If so, do I run it before the Markdown is converted or after? Can I achieve this more simply? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

stephen